# When I add inner shadow for circle, shadow is not round

Tags: css, svg, shadow, svg-filters

When I add inner shadow for circle, shadow is not round
How to fix it, I need that shadow will be without
[corners (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYvXC.png)

I need that shadow in the circle will be rounded
Below you can see my code with filters for circle

```
<svg>
  <defs>
     <filter id={`inset-shadow_${id}`}>
      <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha">
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation={innerShadow.blur}></feGaussianBlur>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius={innerShadow.spread} />

      <feOffset
        in="desenfoque"
        dx={innerShadow.x}
        dy={innerShadow.y}
        result="offsetblur"
      ></feOffset>
      <feFlood flood-color={innerShadowColor} result="color" />
      <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in" />
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />

      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <ellipse
    cx={radius[0]}
    cy={radius[1]}
    rx={rx + sw / 2}
    ry={ry + sw / 2}
    fill={fill}
    stroke={isStroked ? stroke : undefined}
    strokeWidth={sw}
    opacity={transparency / 100}
    strokeDasharray={strokeDasharray}
    strokeDashoffset={strokeDashoffset}
    pointerEvents="none"
    strokeLinecap="round"
    strokeLinejoin="round"
    filter={
      innerShadow && isInnerShadowVisible
        ? `url(#inset-shadow_${id})`
        : undefined
    }
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your code to plain SVG. Ideally in the form of [a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the other question you wrote. Don't use feMorphology - it uses a square kernel which distorts shapes. Instead use an componenttransfer on the alpha.

```
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1.5"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
```